# Exporting a Trinidad Table to Excel

Tags: excel, jsf-1.2, trinidad

How do I export a trinidad table into an excel format?
I have `<tr:table>` and some values in it that are displayed using `<tr:column>`.

I want to export those values into an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate Excel sheets using Apache Trinidad. What you need to do is write an action which:

1. converts the data to an Excel sheet (for example using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [Java Excel API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)) and
2. gets the `HttpServletResponse`, resets it, sets the correct headers and outputs your Excel sheet.

See:

- [Create Excel file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176080/create-excel-file-in-java)
- [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean)

Comment: Can i use tomahawk for this purpose?

Comment: Although I never used Tomahawk, you could check out http://myfaces.apache.org/sandbox-project/tomahawk-sandbox12/tagdoc/s_exporterActionListener.html

Comment: thank you for that doc. But now the problem is i am unable to get start with tomahawk in my project

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that in any other way then pointing you to the documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Quick+Start