# Create and Download Excel from Web Explorer with Java in Spring MVC

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc

I want to create an Excel file from a method in Java and download it in a browser.

I have found an example on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15271706/4815994) where you create the Excel file, but I want to create the `.xls` file and download it from a web browser.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to download the file in a web browser? Or you would like to visualize the excel file in a web browser?

Comment: Just download the created file in a location in my PC, just like a regular download...

Comment: Where will the file be? Locally on your machine, or somewhere on a server?

Comment: Locally in my machine...

Comment: Just type this in your browser : file:///C:/path_to_your_file.xls then you will download the file... It has nothing to do with Java or Excel though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not being very clear, I want to create the file from a method in java first...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90454/discussion-between-pmartin8-and-geme23).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem...!!

This is working for me:

```
       @RequestMapping("/downloadFile")
       public void downloadFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {             

       try {

            String fileName = "C:/excelFile.xls";
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("firstSheet");

            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
            rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("No.");
            rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
            rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Address");
            rowhead.createCell(3).setCellValue("Email");

            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("1");
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Carlos");
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Costa Rica");
            row.createCell(3).setCellValue("myNameh@gmail.com");

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

            //Code to download
            File fileToDownload = new File(fileName);
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);

            // Gets MIME type of the file
            String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileName);

            if (mimeType == null) {
                // Set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

            // Modifies response
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setContentLength((int) fileToDownload.length());

            // Forces download
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileToDownload.getName());
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

            // obtains response's output stream
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            in.close();
            outStream.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded at client successfully");


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a Java process from a Web Browser (HTTP request), then you need an application server (like Tomcat) to accept your HTTP request and execute some server-side code (Servlet). A main method like in the example cannot be launched by a HTTP request. Look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/) if you never wrote a Servlet before.

Comment: Now, you see how important it is to be clear in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with Excel, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers) shows how to download a file from a Spring MVC controler.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
      // get your file as InputStream
      InputStream is = ...;
      // copy it to response's OutputStream
      org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
      response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.info("Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '{}'", fileName, ex);
      throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }
}
```